# SQL Query Using Joining Tables, Group By, and Where

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Question:
Which orders have a value greater than $5,000?

Query I am currently using:

```
SELECT o.orderNumber, o.orderDate, d.quantityOrdered*d.priceEach AS totalAmt
FROM orderdetails d, orders o, products p 
WHERE p.productCode = d.productCode 
    AND d.orderNumber = o.orderNumber;
```

Output Looks Like:

```
'10100','2003-01-06 00:00:00','4080'
'10100','2003-01-06 00:00:00','2754.5'
'10100','2003-01-06 00:00:00','1660.12'
'10100','2003-01-06 00:00:00','1729.21'
'10101','2003-01-09 00:00:00','2701.5'
'10101','2003-01-09 00:00:00','4343.56'
'10101','2003-01-09 00:00:00','1463.8500000000001'
'10101','2003-01-09 00:00:00','2040.1000000000001'
```

As you can see each order has multiple products ordered for it so for example I need the query to combine all of the totalAmt's for Order 10101 to compare it to greater than or equal to 5,000.

Comment: Please use modern `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.  It's the 21st Century already.

Comment: A simple `SUM()` will do.

Comment: Why is `products` in your `join`? Because you are not selecting anything from this table.

Comment: Joining "products" table is needed if you want to sum the products in order only for the product that is existed in the "products" table.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how the table `products` is needed in this query.
Join the tables `orders` and `orderdetails` and sum over `quantityOrdered*priceEach`:

```
SELECT 
  o.orderNumber, 
  o.orderDate, 
  SUM(d.quantityOrdered*d.priceEach) totalamt
FROM orders o INNER JOIN orderdetails d
ON d.orderNumber = o.orderNumber
GROUP BY
  o.orderNumber, 
  o.orderDate
HAVING totalamt > 5000
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to sum the order amount by using SUM() function and GROUP BY function(). So It will be :

```
SELECT
    o.orderNumber,
    o.orderDate,
    SUM(d.quantityOrdered * d.priceEach) AS totalAmt
FROM
    orderdetails d,
    orders o,
    products p
WHERE
    p.productCode = d.productCode
AND d.orderNumber = o.orderNumber
GROUP BY
    o.orderNumber,
    o.orderDate
HAVING
    SUM(d.quantityOrdered * d.priceEach) >= 5000;
```

One thing worth to note: Joining "products" table is needed if you only want to sum the product value for the product that is existed in the "products" table.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need the product table for this?
anyway, use SUM() with group GROUP BY and HAVING would get the result you need.

```
SELECT
    o.orderNumber,
    o.orderDate,
    SUM(d.quantityOrdered * d.priceEach) AS totalAmt
FROM
    orderdetails d,
    orders o,
    products p
WHERE
    p.productCode = d.productCode
AND d.orderNumber = o.orderNumber
GROUP BY
    o.orderNumber
HAVING
    totalAmt >= 5000;
```

Output would be something like this.

```
    '10100' 2003-01-06 00:00:00 10223.83
    '10101' 2003-01-09 00:00:00 10549.01
```

Answer (score 0):

a. Use [group by] in subquery and then filter in parent query
b. Use having

Answer (score 0):

First you don't need the `products` table in your join because no column from this table is participated in the select projection, and for combining records, you need to group them by `orderNumber` and `orderDate` and aggregate the rest of columns by `MAX` function which in your case is `d.quantityOrdered * d.priceEach`:

```
SELECT o.orderNumber, o.orderDate, MAX(d.quantityOrdered * d.priceEach) AS totalAmt
FROM orderdetails d, orders o
WHERE d.orderNumber = o.orderNumber
GROUP BY o.orderNumber, o.orderDate
HAVING MAX(d.quantityOrdered * d.priceEach) > 5000
```